# Conditional logit in Stata

Tags: predictive-modeling, logistic-regression, stata

**Question**: Can Stata present or output the actual betas/coefficients in a datasheet when it performs the conditional logit model?

I understand that Stata has a "predict" capability, but I need to store the betas/coefficients and use them later, after new factor values have been calculated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the command you are looking for is outreg2. For other output options check out [this page](http://www.cpc.unc.edu/research/tools/data_analysis/statatutorial/misc/exporting_results).